# 静的配列を実装するために書かれた C++ プログラムの意味が知りたい

Tags: c++

C++初心者で下記コードを読んでみたところ、以下の通りたくさんの疑問点がありました。お手数をおかけしますがご教示頂けますと幸いです。

1. 3行目： `#ifndef LIST` を使う意味について。
2. 14行目： `List()` の意味について。とりわけ、`（）`が何を指すのか。
3. 24行目： `bool empty() const` の意味について。とりわけ、`const`がなぜ`empty()`の後ろにあるのか。
4. 34行目： `void insert(ElementType item, int pos)` の意味について。とりわけ、なぜ`void`を使うのか。
5. 67行目： `void display(ostream & out) const` の意味について。とりわけ、`&`が何を示すのか。

---

```
#include <iostream>

#ifndef LIST
#define LIST

const int CAPACITY = 1024;
typedef int ElementType;

class List
{
 public:
 /******** Function Members ********/
   /***** Class constructor *****/
   List();
   /*----------------------------------------------------------------------
     Construct a List object.

     Precondition:  None
     Postcondition: An empty List object has been constructed;
         mySize is 0.
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

   /***** empty operation *****/
   bool empty() const;
   /*----------------------------------------------------------------------
     Check if a list is empty.

     Precondition:  None
     Postcondition: true is returned if the list is empty, 
         false if not.
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

   /***** insert and erase *****/
   void insert(ElementType item, int pos);
   /*----------------------------------------------------------------------
     Insert a value into the list at a given position.

     Precondition:  item is the value to be inserted; there is room in 
         the array (mySize < CAPACITY); and the position satisfies
         0 <= pos <= mySize. 
     Postcondition: item has been inserted into the list at the position
         determined by pos (provided there is room and pos is a legal
         position).
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

   void erase(int pos);
   /*----------------------------------------------------------------------
     Remove a value from the list at a given position.

     Precondition:  The list is not empty and the position satisfies
         0 <= pos < mySize.
     Postcondition: element at the position determined by pos has been
         removed (provided pos is a legal position).
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

   /***** output *****/
   void display(ostream & out) const;
   /*----------------------------------------------------------------------
     Display a list.

     Precondition:  out is a reference parameter 
     Postcondition: The list represented by this List object has been
         inserted into ostream out. 
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

 private:
 /******** Data Members ********/
   int mySize;                     // current size of list stored in myArray
   ElementType myArray[CAPACITY];  // array to store list elements

}; //--- end of List class

//------ Prototype of output operator
ostream & operator<< (ostream & out, const List & aList);

#endif
```

出典: Nyhoff, [ADTs, Data Structures and Problem Solving with C++](http://cms.dt.uh.edu/Faculty/LinH/courses/cs3304/Slides/42444-Nyhoff_5-8ppts/Chapter06/CodeSamplesChapter06.htm), Second Edition, Figure 6.1A List.h Using Static Array　p262~264 © 2005 Pearson Education, Inc. All rights reserved. 0-13-140909-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

まず、このファイル "List.h" は、 **ヘッダーファイル** と呼ばれるものです。このファイルは、`List` クラスにどのようなメソッドがあり、どう使えるのかを示すために書かれています。`List` クラスの実装は与えていないことに注意してください（それは別ファイル "List.cpp" として与えられています）。

ご質問の数が多いので、それぞれに短い回答を書きます。もし疑問点があれば、個別に新しく質問をご投稿ください。

#### 1. `#ifndef LIST` を使う意味

これは **インクルードガード** と呼ばれているテクニックです。ヘッダーファイルが複数のソースファイルから複数回 `#include` されたとしても `List` クラスの定義が重複しないようにするための書き方です。詳しくは[「PRE06-C. ヘッダファイルはインクルードガードで囲む」](https://www.jpcert.or.jp/sc-rules/c-pre06-c.html)をご覧ください。

#### 2. `List()` の意味について

`List` クラスの **コンストラクタ** の定義です。cppreference.com の ["Constructors and member initializer lists"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) をご覧ください。

#### 3. `bool empty() const` の意味

コメントに書いてあるように、`List` オブジェクトが空かどうかを判定するメソッド `empty` の定義です。定義のこの場所に `const` を書いた場合、`this`、つまり今見ているリスト自身の型が `const List *` になることを意味しています。 **`const` は書いた位置によって意味が変わる** ので、詳しくは別の質問[「C++クラスでのconstの定義方法について」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1861/19110)をご覧ください。

#### 4. `void insert(ElementType item, int pos)` の意味

コメントに書いてあるように、`List` オブジェクトに新しい要素を追加するメソッド `insert` の定義です。つまり、`this` オブジェクトを書き換えて新しい要素を追加するだけなので、戻り値は必要ありません（`void` 型になります）。<sup>(註: 実装の仕方によっては、要素を追加する度に新しい `List` オブジェクトを返すようにすることもできますが、ここではそうしていないということです。)</sup>

#### 5. `void display(ostream & out) const` の意味

コメントに書いてあるように、`List` オブジェクトを表示する (`ostream` に出力する) ためのメソッド `display` の定義です。`ostream & out` の `&` は、 **参照型** を表すための記号です。参照型を短く説明できる自信が無いので、Wikipedia の ["Reference (C++)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) や Qiita の[「C++ 値渡し、ポインタ渡し、参照渡しを使い分けよう」](https://qiita.com/agate-pris/items/05948b7d33f3e88b8967)をご覧ください。

#### 補足

今回ご質問頂いた部分は、C++ の言語機能の中でも基本となるものが多いです。もし「ヘッダーファイル」「コンストラクタ」「参照渡し」などの言葉に聞き馴染みが無ければ、短いウェブサイトより先に C++ の入門書を読んで、体系的にまとまった知識を得ることをオススメします。

Comment: 当方、現在c++を学習中の学生のため、生半可な知識で質問したにも関わらずご回答頂きありがとうございました。まずは基礎固めをしたいと思います。

Answer (score 3):

＞1.3行目： #ifndef LIST を使う意味について。

→多重定義によるビルドエラー発生を防止する為のケアでしょう。

＞2.14行目： List() の意味について。とりわけ、（）が何を指すのか。

→コンストラクタです。
　クラス名生成時に呼ばれる特殊なメソッドです。
　初期化処理等を記述します。
　~List()とあった場合はデストラクタで、クラスのオブジェクトが破棄される際に呼ばれます。
　デストラクタはメモリの開放など、終了処理を記述します。

＞3.24行目： bool empty() const の意味について。とりわけ、constがなぜempty()の後ろにあるのか。

→メソッド名の後ろにつけたconstは、該当メソッド内でのメンバー変数の値の変更を禁止するという意味です。

＞4.34行目： void insert(ElementType item, int pos)の意味について。とりわけ、なぜvoidを使うのか

→このメソッドは戻り値を返却しない事を示しています（return で変数を返却しない）。
　コンストラクタ、デストラクタ等、特殊なメソッド以外、メソッドには必ず戻り値の指定をする必要があり、
　値を返却しない事を明示的にするために上記の様な記述をします。

＞5.67行目： void display(ostream & out) constの意味について。とりわけ、&が何を示すのか。

→引数を"参照渡し"で受け取るという記述です。
　引数は基本的に、値渡し、ポインタ渡し、参照渡しという３つの方法で与える事ができます。
　呼出元で指定した変数を、呼出先のメソッド内のスコープでも扱う事が可能となります。
　"関数のスコープ"で調べてみて下さい。